# How to put LEGO together upside down

Tags: building, snot

I'm building a truck. For the transmission, I want to make it all even and symmetrical.

To do that I need the pieces to stay together but they have no studs connecting so they will just fall apart.

Does anybody have any suggestions to keep them together besides using the light saber shaft?

This is the main chassis for the truck.

This is what I want the transmission to look like, but it's quite big so I want it smaller. As you can see, the arch bricks won't go together this way so I need an idea to keep them together.

[image]

Comment: There's a couple of suggestions in [this question](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/42/56) where people have answered the opposite of the original question.

Comment: Technic bricks can easily be attached with the studs in different orientations. Or minifig hands can be used to attach plates back to back with no gap if you don't need a lot of stiction.

Answer (score 14):

I attempt to create [a searchable index of SNOT techniques](http://swooshable.com/snot?degree=180), as this is called. Of those, the strongest 180 degree stud reversal are probably one of these:

[image]

[image]

If you want to connect the two curves together bottom to bottom, you should be able to do it with an axle, sort of like these two techniques:

[image]

[image]

If that doesn't work I once had luck playing around with a lever and a rubber band. It was tricky, but it did work:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I think this is how we did it as kids. However, it was 1970s. Probably too primitive, clumsy, or against the rules now. 
[image]

Comment: You can build [a similar design](https://www.flickr.com/photos/legomonster/4531528223/in/faves-ambo100/) which I find is stronger (but slightly larger) using cheese slopes and a plate and brick of the same size. It can also be built with [two plates and cheese slopes](https://www.flickr.com/photos/legomonster/4532163942/in/set-72157621862416111).

Comment: @Ambo100 Post that as an answer, it's the best one here!

Answer (score 5):

Generally, the lampholder plate does the job:

http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4081b

but some idea of the scale you are working in will help get a better answer, or if you can post a picture of the model you might get a specific answer.

Comment: In addition, you can also use technic pegs to join bricks base to base.  This is an, 'illegal technique,' however, as forcing the peg into the tube will weaken/bend the plastic slightly and make it weaker in the future.

Answer (score 2):

While Windfire's suggestion is valid, there are several [elements with opposing studs](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?q=studs%20on%202%20sides).

Many of the parts listed on that link don't apply, but several do, including the first five.

If you're not clone-averse, [Cobi](http://cobi.pl/en/toys/) makes some great plates with studs on both sides, though I have no idea where you can get them aside from buying entire sets known to contain them.