# Building a window with the tie-fighter round dish

Tags: building, design

Is there an elegant way to build a round window with the [Radial Cockpit Window](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4740pb005#T=P)? I've tried experimenting with vertical clip plates but it just ends up looking odd.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm gonna suggest a SNOT contraption relying on two [3659 Arch 1x4](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3659), two 1x1 round plates in trans clear, and one [2654 2x2 round plate with rounded bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2654#T=C&C=12), also in trans-clear:

[image: contraption CAD drawing]

The 2x2 plus 1x1 round plates should just fit within the arches of the arch bricks and provide just enough friction to hold:

[image: Detail of cross-section]

If stability is a bigger concern, replace one of the 1x1 round plates with a 2x2 plate in trans-clear. This should keep the window from wiggling:

[image: contraption CAD drawing]

There *should* be enough room inside the 1x4 arch brick to snugly accommodate the 2x2 plate:

[image: Detail of cross-section]

Comment: And then see [Joubarc's answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/431/56) for details on securing this within your build.

Comment: I'd rather recommend reading The Unnofficial LEGO Advanced Building Techniques Guide (from https://www.brickshelf.com/gallery/KimT/Mixed/Instructions/advbuilding.pdf ), and in particular the SNOT 180 chapter.

Answer (score 3):

It's also possible to use the (relatively new) part [78666 Arch 1x2 Inverted](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=78666) together with [3659Arch 1x4](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3659) to achieve a SNOT-less window frame, for example:

[image: CAD diagram of window assembly]

Bear in mind that the curve of the inverted 1x2 arches is not the same as the 1x4 arch, and there'll be a small (about 1/10<sup>th</sup> of a stud) gap between the inverted arches and the 2x2 dish:

[image: CAD diagram showing gap]